# Authentication Failure when accessing visualSVN server from linux svn client

Tags: linux, svn, visualsvn-server

Our VisualSVN server has "Integrated Windows Authentication" enabled, so I cannot access to it via Ubuntu/svn.

When I do this :

```
svn checkout http://MyRepo
```

I get these errors:

> svn: E120191: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://MyRepo' 
>   svn: E120191: Error running context: The requested authentication type(s) are not supported.

Does anybody know a solution to this problem (other than not using Windows Authentication) ?

Answer (score 3):

1. If you have Integrated Windows Authentication enabled, then your client computer has to be joined the Active Directory domain where VisualSVN Server resides (or at least trusted AD domain). In such case Integrated Windows Authentication will work from the Linux machine (over Kerberos or NTLM) without any problems.
2. For a non-domain Windows machine, it is always possible to put AD credentials to [Windows Credential Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-credential-manager) and you could authenticate over IWA without any issues. I don't know any alternative on Linux for the tool but I guess that there has to be one.
3. You can enable Basic Windows Authentication in VisualSVN Server settings in addition to Integrated Windows Authentication. This way Linux-based should be able to authenticate over Basic.